# Swift 3 - Function Inside DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, dispatch-queue

I called a function inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Here's my code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for i in 0 ... (Global.selectedIcons.count - 1) {
            if self.albumorphoto == 1 {
                if i == 0 {
                    self.detector = 1
                    self.uploadPhoto() //here
                }
                else {
                    self.detector = 2
                    self.uploadPhoto() //here
                }
            }
            else {
                self.uploadPhoto() //here
            }
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("done")
    }
}

func uploadPhoto(){
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let params = param

    request.httpBody = params.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error!)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response!)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

        if self.detector == 1 {
            self.album = self.parseJsonData(data: data)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(data: Data) -> [AnyObject] {
    do {
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        let jsonalbum = jsonResult!["data"] as? [AnyObject]
        for jsonAlbum in jsonalbum! {
            self.folderID = jsonAlbum["id"] as! String
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return album
}
```

I wish to make it wait until all the tasks in `DispathcQueue` finish. It works but the problem is my function `uploadPhoto()`. It can't wait until `uploadPhoto()` finish doing its task. Any idea to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `completionBlock`.

Comment: where are you entering the group ?

Comment: @CZ54 sorry I accidentally remove it. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `DispatchGroup` is the right choice here, but you have to `enter` and `leave` for each asynchronous task:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
photos.forEach { photo in

    group.enter()
    // create the request for the photo

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        group.leave()
        // handle the response

    }.resume()
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("All photos uploaded.")
}
```

You don't need a `DispatchQueue.async()` call because `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is already asynchronous.

In my code i assumed that you want to model your objects as `Photo` and replace `Global.selectedIcons.count` with a `photos` array:

```
class Photo {
    let isAlbum: Bool
    let isDefector: Bool
    let imageData: Data
}
```

I'd recommend you take a look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to further improve your code. These are popular libraries that make dealing with network requests a lot easier. With them you can reduce almost the entire `uploadPhoto()`/`parseJsonData()` functions to something like this:

```
Alamofire.upload(photo.imageData, to: url).responseSwiftyJSON { json in
    json["data"].array?.compactMap{ $0["id"].string }.forEach {
        self.folderID = $0
    }
}
```

This makes your code more stable because it removes all forced unwrapping. Alamofire also provides you with features like upload progress and resuming & cancelling of requests.